# MS SQL Server High Data File I/O Latency

Tags: sql-server

we are currently having problems with our MS SQL Server Performance.
The Data File IO goes up to 70 MS, but we cannot find this problem in our Hypervisor-Monitoring. The Response Times there are maximum 600 µs in spikes. Same thing is in the resmon, here we have an maximum of 2 ms response time. Mostly 1 ms.

I thought the problem might be our Antivirus software, so i tried to add exclusions and even disabled it completly with no positive results.

Does anyone have a clue, what we can check?
I tried to search for help, but the only things i can find are, that maybe the drives are to slow, what i would say isnt the case with that response times. Or that the antivirus could be a problem, but i disabled it and the Problem consists.

Thanks.

Comment: //The CPU is sleeping at 10-20%
The 100GBs of RAM are mostly reserved by the SQL Server, but this should be normal.

Comment: Is there anything in the Sql Server error log?  How much memory is on the server total and what is the MaxMem setting on the Sql Server instance running on the server?

Comment: There are no errors regarding to this. Some failed logins, but that shouldnt be a problem.
110 GB RAM for the machine, and the maxmem is set to 80GB

Comment: Which hypervisor is the VM running on? What type of storage adapter is seen by the VM?

Comment: VMWare ESXI
It  is shown as Local AVAGO Disk

Answer (score 1):

### Use Perfmon for Investigating SQL Server disk performance issues.

I recommend starting with Perfmon - "Logical Disk" counters when investigation SQL Server IO issues.  It serves as a good demarcation point between low level and high level issues.  If you see bad performance in perfmon, then it's a safe bet to look lower.. (physical adapters, vm host configuration, san performance, etc., i.e. it's **not SQL Server**.) If perfmon looks good, then it's a higher level issue (SQL Server, anti-virus, etc).

### Grab a baseline and sanity check it.

Measure the latencies (Logical Disk - avg sec/read, avg sec/write) and IOPS (disk reads/sec, disk writes/sec) for the drive(s) that hold the data and log files.  Review those numbers with the storage admin.  Are they reasonable? Lower or higher than expected?

All servers have different IO requirements, so your "normal" may be very different from mine.  My current rules of thumb:

- Over 3k-5k read or write IOPS is busy and probably needs special coordination with the storage folks.
- Less than 500 IOPS is not very busy, so probably doesn't matter.
- < 10ms latency is usually good enough reads.  <5ms for writes.
- blips higher (50-100ms) can be tolerated.  Sustained high latencies (>100ms) are unacceptable.
- Be flexible... give some leeway during large data loads or nightly maintenance windows.

The latencies in perfmon are absolutely key. They will either point you up or down the IO stack.  Don't waste time investigating wrong direction.

### Perfmon looks good, but SQL is showing slow disk IO.

If perfmon looks good and SQL is still seeing high latencies, then quadruple check that AV software is excluding the .mdf/ndf/ldf files.  Also check for any other software that may be watching the filesystem. Investigate mini-filter drivers. Overall CPU shouldn't be pegged. Confirm SQL is using the all the CPU's.

Answer (score 0):

> but we cannot find this problem in our Hypervisor-Monitoring.

I take it that you are running SQL Server, a Guest Operating System, inside of another Guest Operating system, on a Hypervisor host (VMWARE, Any Cloud VM instance, etc...)

If so, you are going to have issues of brokered access to resources where the hypervisor is making a decision on who gets attention amongst the guests.  You can minimize the overhead by pinning certain hardware resources to particular guests.  If you have any shared resources amongst guests and your SQL Server instance this could be the root of periodic, unpredictable delays as the second or third guest gets interrupt priority on the shared resource.

This arbitration overhead is at the root of why you get lower TPC-C times running inside of a virtual machine as an arbitrated guest than as running as a single Guest in an on hardware OS.   As a guest OS, database servers (SQL Server, ORACLE, DB2, ...) prefer to grab a pool of resource (Disk, RAM) and manage it themselves for highest performance with lowest intrusion from the OS.  Running in a virtual machine guarantees that some skew is added back in.

As a second thought, you might also have some skew in your timing data captured inside of a guest virtual machine.  The system clock is virtualized and floats in relationship to the hardware clock.  Periodically this floating clock in the VM requires truing up.  The manifestation of this is something called clock jump, where the slowed virtual clock is brought back into sync with the hardware clock.   If this jump happens while you have a timing record open then you will have a longer response at time of the timing record close even though the actual time is shorter.   The amount of skew depends upon the clock jump during the sync.   This condition is observed quite often in multi-user performance testing where hundreds of processes are generating load against applications for test and where the users are staged on virtual machines.  The check against this is to always have a control load generator on hardware and use the control subset for the best understanding of response time performance